# Iterating over a loop causes out of gas error

Tags: solidity, out-of-gas

I have an array of json objects, which contain an id and 5 fields. I have a function to register these fields against a unique identifier within a contract.

```
contract Test {  
    struct Product {  
        uint p_id,  
        uint qty
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => Product) ProdMap;

    function registerProduct (bytes32 id, uint p, uint q) returns (bool) {
        ProdMap[id].p_id = p;
        ProdMap[id].qty = q;
    }
}
```

I am able to interact with a contract get a transaction hash out of the executed transaction in a contract:

```
contractInstance.registerProduct.sendTransaction(
    web3.fromAscii("0abc123"),
    items[0].Product_ID,
    items[0].Quantity,
    {
        from:web3.eth.accounts[0],
        gas:470000
    }, 
    function(err,txid) {
        if(err) { console.log(err); }
        var hash = txid;
        console.log('Transaction registered '+'and transaction hash is: ' + hash);
        callback(null,hash);
    });
```

Here items is an array if json objects. But when I loop through the entire array, I am getting an out of gas error.

```
contractInstance.registerProduct.sendTransaction(
    web3.fromAscii(item.Line_Item_ID),
    item.Product_ID,
    item.Quantity,
    {
        from:web3.eth.accounts[0],
        gas:1000000
    }, 
    function(err,txid) {
        if(err) {console.log(err);}
        var hash = txid;
        console.log('Transaction registered '+'and transaction hash is: ' + hash);
        callback(null,hash);
    });
```

Here I have listed only 2 attributes, but I have 5 in all while registering the product. I have been using testrpc and when I set the limit to a really high amount 4500000000000, I am able to execute the transactions. But when I see the logs for testrpc, the gas used is 27608. Is it possible to determine the gas needed to execute a transaction? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a estimateGas() method, you can invoke like this:

```
contractInstance.registerProduct.sendTransaction.estimateGas(
    web3.fromAscii(item.Line_Item_ID),
    item.Product_ID,
    item.Quantity,
    {
        from:web3.eth.accounts[0]
   }, 
   function(err,txid) {
        if(err) {console.log(err);}
        var hash = txid;
        console.log('Transaction registered '+'and transaction hash is: ' + hash);
        callback(null,hash);
   });
```

Comment: You have an extra `sendTransaction` in your example that should not be needed.